# Is it possible to extract specific({Architect, Building}) information from unstructured text chunks using NLP?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am working on a task to extract architects and their buildings from unstructured pieces of texts with varying sizes. I started trying a NLP tool called SpaCy but annotations they provide sometimes mixes up.

**FAC** Buildings, airports, highways, bridges, etc.

**ORG** Companies, agencies, institutions, etc.

**GPE** Countries, cities, states.

**LOC** Non-GPE locations, mountain ranges, bodies of water.

Building names falls into those 4 annotations. My job would be so much easier if i could get only **FAC** for building names but it looks like it is not possible or i couldn't be able to make it work.

The question is, is it even possible to use NLP tools to extract such information tuples(in my case {Architect, Building}) from a chunk of text?

Edit: Some things i have done

Following bits are some examples of texts i am using at the moment

> He renovated Fatih Mosque and built Laleli Mosque in the name of
> Sultan Mustafa III
>
> Mehmed Tahir Ağa built Hamidiyye Complex in Bahçekapı for Sultan
> Abdülhamid I.

I am giving those texts as data to the spaCy, code bit is here:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
text = data[i]
text = re.sub(r'\([^()]*\)', '', text)
doc = nlp(text)

#Extract ORG, GPE, LOC and FAC labels from phrases
for entity in doc.ents:
    if entity.label_ in ('ORG', 'GPE', 'LOC', 'FAC'):
        #Manual filtering of results
        if entity.text not in ("Istanbul", "Egypt", "Hicaz", "Palestine", "Syria", "Balkans", "Albania", "Malta", "Spain", "Bosnia", "Frengistan", "Kırım", "Belgrade", "Damascus"):
            print(entity.text, entity.label_)
```

Output is:

Laleli Mosque ORG

Hamidiyye Complex ORG

Bahçekapı for Sultan Abdülhamid I. ORG

Comment: Can you share some example texts? All this is very context dependent, hence examples are the best way to approach this. It would be also great, if you can add all the work you have done this far.

Comment: @Raqib I added some examples and a code bit. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for adding more information. This is a classic NLP problem called Named Entity Recognition (NER). You problem is very much solvable. You accuracy you will get with the out of box spacy models is going to be low because the information spaCy was trained on is different from the information you are using it for. Hence, you will need to help teach spaCy in your context. You can find more information [here](https://spacy.io/usage/training). If it doesnt make sense, comment here again, and we can try further.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how closely the text you're working with follows the structure of the data that SpaCy's default models were trained with. If they're very different, you might have to train your own model instead of using theirs. The guys behind SpaCy (explosion.ai) have a paid tool that can help you do this (prodi.gy). That said, it probably is possible to do what you want to do, but putting together a training set without tool support is not a very easy thing to do.